# Virtual Destinations Active and client id wildcard

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I have been reading the documentation for virtual destinations here: http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html

But I hit a bit of a snag, when I send to a topic it does not seem to follow the client id name as described on the document

My setup on the active mq is:

```
    <destinationInterceptors>
      <virtualDestinationInterceptor>
        <virtualDestinations>
          <virtualTopic name="Destination.>" prefix="Target.*." selectorAware="false" />
        </virtualDestinations>
      </virtualDestinationInterceptor>
    </destinationInterceptors>
```

The code above describes that when I send to a **Destination.Status** topic with a **ClientId** of **CustomerA**.

It should send only to **Target.CustomerA.Destination.Status** if understand correctly, but what's happening is it's sending to **Target.CustomerA.Destination.Status** and **Target.CustomerB.Destination.Status** so basically fanning out messages to queues and ignoring the client id.

I did not see any further documentation about how to configure it, i was wondering if anyone else encountered this ?

Am I missing something here ?
Below is my producer if it's helpful.

```
    public static class HelloWorldProducer implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            try {
                // Create a ConnectionFactory
                ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61617");

                // Create a Connection
                Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
                connection.setClientID("CustomerA");
                connection.start();

                // Create a Session
                Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

                // Create the destination (Topic or Queue)
                Destination destination = session.createTopic("Destination.Status");
                // Create a MessageProducer from the Session to the Topic or Queue
                MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
                producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);

                // Create a messages
                String text = "Hello world! From: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + this.hashCode();
                TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(text);

                // Tell the producer to send the message
                System.out.println("Sent message: "+ message.hashCode() + " : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                producer.send(message);

                // Clean up
                session.close();
                connection.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Caught: " + e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Any inputs will be beneficial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sender in this scenario has no real effect on the routing at the broker whether or not you've set a ClientID as it is just sending to a named Topic, in this case "Destination.Status".  The configuration on the broker controls the routing and in your case you've configured "Destination.>" so any Queue consumer that comes along and subscribes to a Queue that matches the configuration you've set.  So in your case I'd guess you have one consumer subscribing to Queue (Target.CustomerA.Destination.Status) and one to Queue (Target.CustomerB.Destination.Status) which then causes any message sent to the Topic to be fanned out to both.

If you want competing consumers then you'd need to subscribe both to Target.CustomerA.Destination.Status and then the broker would round-robin dispatch the sent message to either of the active subscribers.

Comment: I see, so the wildcard is meant for consumers of any client id to be able to consume to the queues and the virtual topic to be able to send to it right ?
Meaning all queues that fall under the destination will basically receive all messages without routing from the topic(which makes sense, they receive those on the topic).
Making the pubsub for that client, or any client on the matter durable in a way.
Virtual destinations just fan out dynamically based on what you set on the destination.
Thanks for this as I thought there was routing capabilities for the virtual destination.

Comment: Please mark as resolved so others know this has been answered

Comment: You can of course add selector aware capabilities to the mix which allows for some finer grained control over which queues get what.